# Eclipse: To support older versions than API 17 (project specifies 8)

Tags: java, android, eclipse

The error that I'm encountering:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout: layout_alignParentStart
- To support older versions than API 17 (project specifies 8) you should 
 *also* add android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
```

My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:id="@+id/txtContacts"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is a code from Android studio, I just copy and pasted it to eclipse, though the layout works perfectly, but the code is receiving an error. I already tried installing the required API level, but still it won't work.

even in the button of my eclipse:

```
android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
```

but the holo green light appears perfectly in graphical layout, but it is just the code is red, it's an error.

- And btw I am using an API 19: 4.4.2 and I've already installed API 17. But still the error persist.

Comment: [Google Stops Development And Support For ADT In Eclipse](http://www.techtimes.com/articles/64494/20150630/google-stops-development-and-support-for-adt-in-eclipse.htm)

Comment: So you have to remove one attribute and add another. Now did you? Why would that be a problem?

Comment: Everything is good now! Thank you for the comments..